# constant pointer to an address or pointer to a value

Tags: c, pointers, constants

Do `int const *a` and `const int *a` mean that "a is a integer pointer to a constant value" and "a is a pointer to a constant address", respectively , or is it viceversa?

This was asked to me in an interview. After reading a lot about the same I am still very much confused regarding it.

Comment: In C++ it's usually not about reading "a lot", but about reading the right things :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `const int *a` - `a` is writable (can point to a different thing), `*a` is not writable (cannot write to pointed-to thing)
- `int const *a` - same as above
- `int * const a` - `a` is not writeable (cannot point to a different thing), `*a` is writable (can write to pointed-to thing)
- `const int * const a` - neither `a` nor `*a` are writable
- `int const * const a` - same as above

If you read the first two cases as

```
const int (*a)
int const (*a)
```

it's clear that the `const` is modifying the `int` type specifier; we're pointing to a *constant integer*.

If you read the third case as

```
int (* const a)
```

then the `const` is modifying the pointer declarator `*a`; we have a *constant pointer* to an integer.

Then you read the final two cases as

```
(const int) (* const a)
(int const) (* const a)
```

then it's clear that we have one `const` modifying the type specifier and the other modifying the pointer, so we have a *constant pointer* to a *constant integer*.

Comment: i gather that writing-> const int *a or int const *a ->means a is a pointer to a constant object and writing -> int (*const a) mean ->a is pointer to a constant address.

Comment: more like, `const int *a` means `a` is a non-`const` pointer to a `const` object, and `int * const a` means `a` is a `const` pointer to a non-`const` object.

Answer (score 2):

When the `const` hops over the type keyword (`int`), the meaning doesn't change.

The meaning changes when the `const` hops over the `*`.

```
const int *a; /* The int is const */
int const *b; /* The int is const */
int *const c; /* The pointer is const */
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int const *a;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
const int *a;
```

means `a` is a pointer to a `const int` object.