# Is a constant char pointer a pointer that points to a constant char or a constant pointer that points to a char?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I was working on a piece of code when I noticed that syntactically, it isn't possible to distinguish a constant pointer pointing to a char type from a pointer pointing to a constant char type, at least not to my knowledge. Either way I try and put it, I just end up with this: `const char * foo;`.

Also if there is a way of distinguishing between the two, please let me know in your answer or the comments below.

Thank you.

Comment: `const char * foo` is a pointer to a `const char` (the character it points to cannot be changed). `char * const foo` is a const pointer to a `char`, so you can change the char, but not the value of the pointer.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/q/22332677/2564301 help? (If not a factual duplicate.)

Answer (score 2):

```
const char * foo;
```

above `foo` is a pointer to constant char. Meaning you can't change object contents to which pointer points.

```
char * const foo;
```

above `foo` is a constant pointer to char. Meaning you can change object contents to which pointer points to, but you can't assign other object to the pointer.

[This](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) should be useful read to you.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to remember where `const` qualification applies if you put it *after* the type to which it applies

```
char const* a;      // mutable pointer to unmutable char
char*const b;       // unmutable pointer to mutable char
char const*const c; // both unmutable
char* c;            // both mutable
```